# How I can type Array.map iterations?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How I can type .map iterations? Typescript show problem

[image: my problem]

```
{userList.items.map(user => (
<tr className='list_row'>
    <td className='list_col1'> {user.username}</td>
    <td className='list_col2'>{user.email}</td>
    <td className='list_col3'>{user.address}</td>
</tr>
))}

const [userList, setUserList] = useState<{
    error?: any;
    isLoaded: boolean;
    items?: Object[];
  }>({
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    items: [],
  });
```

I try create type, but don't understand how use it.

```
type User = {
  username?: string | null;
  email?: string | null;
  address?: string | null;
};
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Copy the code as text into your question.

Comment: I don't understand why you make `items` nullable if you assign a default value to it.

Comment: @NoraSöderlund it small tips for beginers in typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a `User` type, you can use it like this:
`items?: User[]`

```
type User = {
  username?: string | null;
  email?: string | null;
  address?: string | null;
};

const [userList, setUserList] = useState<{
    error?: any;
    isLoaded: boolean;
    items?: User[]; // could be undefined -- User[] | undefined
  }>({
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    items: [],
  });
```

However, if `UserList.items` could be `undefined` or `User[]`, typescript won't let you call `UserList.items.map()`.

So first you need to check that `UserList.items` is not `undefined` before you can map. Otherwise there is a risk of causing a runtime error. eg

```
userList.items && userList.items.map()
```

Or with optional chaining syntax eg

```
userList.items?.map()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't make `items` optional:

```
const [userList, setUserList] = useState<{
    error?: any;
    isLoaded: boolean;
    items: Object[];
  }>({ //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified the type of items as optional Object, Typescript shows this error. In most cases, the value of array is not undefined. It may be empty array ([]) or array of items. So If userList cannot hold undefined for array, you may use that value without optional operator. If you are sure that this state variable will hold array value optionally, then try using **optional chaining** in typescript. Also do the same for user object as well. Since you added all the property of user object as optional

```
{userList?.items?.map(user => (
  <tr className='list_row'>
   <td className='list_col1'> {user?.username}</td>
   <td className='list_col2'>{user?.email}</td>
   <td className='list_col3'>{user?.address}</td>
  </tr>
))}
```